# Cypress - Impossible to type into an input field

Tags: input, cypress

I am trying to automate a form with Cypress. I managed to get all the input fields except the birth date field.
CSS looks like this:
[CSS picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7eLh.png)

And my code is:

```
cy.iframe('#oneid-iframe').find('#InputDOB').type('01011990').should("have.value", "01/01/1990")
```

Unfortunately Cypress fails to type this value in the field.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Kind regards,

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Timed out retrying after 8130ms: expected '<input#InputDOB>' to have value '01/01/1990', but the value was ''

Comment: I got an error at the step -type it was able to find the input field

Comment: cy.iframe is it coming from the cypress iframe plugin or you wrote some custom command?

Comment: I used cy.iframe('#oneid-iframe') because the form is inside a frame. It worked well for the other input fields

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the devtools to see what's in the DOM.

This problem can happen if the HTML in your screenshot is inside a shadow root, in which case this would be your code

```js
it('tests DOB', {includeShadowDom: true}, () => {
  cy.iframe('#oneid-iframe')
    .find('#InputDOB')
    .type('01011990')
    .should("have.value", "01/01/1990")
})
```

This is just a guess, and the question is why do other input work.

But you should try it in case.

Comment: I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
cy.get('#oneid-iframe').its('body').find('#InputDOB').click().type('01011990')

Comment: I have an error: the property 'body' does not exist on your subject

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```js
cy.iframe('#oneid-iframe').find('#InputDOB').invoke('removeAttr','type').type('01/01/1990').should("have.value", "01/01/1990");
```

Comment: I still have the same issue :(

Comment: Hi, I copied the html of the input element you posted, used this code to type into the field, and I type into the text box. 


`cy.get("#InputDOB").type("01011990")`

Is it possible for you to post the link of the webpage where the text field is present?

Answer (score 0):

```
                     <label data-testid="InputDOB-wrapper" class="input-text input-DOB displayed" for="InputDOB">
                    <span data-testid="InputDOB-title" class="field-name">Birth Date</span>
                    <div data-testid="InputDOB-container" class="input-wrapper field-error"><span class="mask"><span class="birth-date">Birth Date </span>dd/mm/yyyy</span><input type="text" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" id="InputDOB" data-testid="InputDOB" inputmode="numeric" aria-label="Birth Date" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="InputDOB-error" value=""></div>
                    <div class="error-container input-error input-error-text displayed" style="height: 30px;">
                       <p class="input-error input-error-text displayed" id="InputDOB-error" data-testid="InputDOB-error" role="alert">Your birth date is required.</p>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)